# Let $\theta_n$ be a random variable that can be $\{\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},...,\frac{n}{n}\}$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: probability

Let $\theta_n$ be a random variable that can be $\{\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},...,\frac{n}{n}\}$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{n}$. My question is where does $\theta_n$ converge in distribution? My guess is $\theta=U[0,1]$ where $U$ is the uniform distribution.

How can I show that?

I tried to sketch a proof like this:

We know that $P(\theta_n\leq\frac{i_n}{n})=\frac{i_n}{n}$, for a sequence $i_n=xn$ we have that $P(\theta_n\leq x)=x,\forall n$, this is the same distribution of the CDF of a uniform distribution, hence $\theta_n \rightarrow_d\theta \sim U[0,1]$.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can't restrict attention to the nice cases, you have to handle arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. To do that, note that for $x \in [0,1]$:

$$P(\theta_n \leq x)=\frac{1}{n} |\{ k \in \mathbb{N} : k/n \leq x \}| \\
= \frac{1}{n} |\{ k \in \mathbb{N} : k \leq nx \}|.$$

How many elements are in that set when $n$ is finite?

The case $x \not \in [0,1]$ is easy of course.